# How to keep users out of system files?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users

I'm trying to build a system that will be as idiot proof as possible.  This will include keeping regular users out of system files to prevent them from rendering the system inoperable.  And hopefully also keep them from reading or accessing files I don't want them to read or access.

I've read that without sudo privileges, users are mostly limited to their home directories for writing and deleting.  Would that be enough to protect the operating system?

Also, is there a way to mostly limit users to their home directory for the file browser?  (I know users still need to access the bin and other directories to run other programs, and I'll be disabling terminal for normal users as well)

Answer (score 1):

Without `sudo`, users are limited to only having access to the `/home` directory in general, and then without permissions being modified for other users' home folders, they can only access their own `home` folder. So, as far as I know, what you're describing is largely the default behavior for non-sudo users.

That said, I think that any user can **read** many files in the system without sudo, but one really can't do anything without write permission anyhow, so I would consider that a moot point.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent unauthorized reading?  Like for example, I'm thinking about 2-way SSL authentication, and I don't want the client private key getting copied.

Comment: That would simply be `chmod 0700 /home/someUser` for each home folder. That'll give the "owner" full permissions, and the "group" and "world" no permissions.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to apply this concept to all system files and folders?  Or not really because the user still needs read permission to bin and other folders?

Comment: AFAIK, the user needs read access to system, so they can utilize the configurations.

Comment: Do NOT mess with system file permissions unless you have a specific reason for doing it and know exactly what you are doing. You might render your system unbootable or unusable or even worse create strange errors you might not notice at first and some poor bastard has to find and fix it a year later when nobody remembers the changes any more. The packagers set the permission for a reason and your changes would be overwritten by updates anyway. If you should discover a security problem with the default permissions you should file a bugreport.