# Configure Thunar to keep users out of system folders?

Tags: permissions, thunar

I'm trying to build a system for public use where the intended use of the file browser (thunar) is to only allow access to home, network shared drives, and any plugged in usb drives.  I would like to prevent them from accessing system folders like for example going "up" from home.  Is there any way to configure thunar in this way?

From my previous question: [How to keep users out of system files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686015/how-to-keep-users-out-of-system-files), I learned that can remove writing and deleting premissions from system files by removing users from the sudo group.  But I don't intend to allow users access to terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this with Thunar. However, you can do:

```
sudo chmod o-x <folder>
```

Which will keep users that don't have user or group privileges for the folder from descending into the folder.
Don't do this to the /home directory, because the user will not be able to get to their home directory. You could try removing read access to the /home  directory:

```
sudo chmod o-r /home
```

This will keep users from seeing any other user's folders, but they should still see their own home folder.